# Is there a way to loop through all fields in a MySQL trigger rather than repeating yourself?

Tags: mysql

Easiest to explain via example.  Here is my MySQL query to create the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tblExample_UPDATE`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `tblExample_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `tblExample`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.field1 != OLD.field1) THEN
        INSERT INTO tblChanges (object_type,object_id,change_type,field_name,field_before,field_after,log_time) VALUES ("example",NEW.id,"edited","field1",OLD.field1,NEW.field1,NOW());
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.field2 != OLD.field2) THEN
        INSERT INTO tblChanges (object_type,object_id,change_type,field_name,field_before,field_after,log_time) VALUES ("example",NEW.id,"edited","field2",OLD.field2,NEW.field2,NOW());
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.field3 != OLD.field3) THEN
        INSERT INTO tblChanges (object_type,object_id,change_type,field_name,field_before,field_after,log_time) VALUES ("example",NEW.id,"edited","field3",OLD.field3,NEW.field3,NOW());
    END IF;
    .
    ..
    ...
    ..
    .    
    IF (NEW.field1337 != OLD.field1337) THEN
        INSERT INTO tblChanges (object_type,object_id,change_type,field_name,field_before,field_after,log_time) VALUES ("example",NEW.id,"edited","field1337",OLD.field1337,NEW.field1337,NOW());
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

So essentially I am checking field by field for changes.  It certainly works but is going to be a PITA to maintain as any schema changes will cause issues.

Is there any way to loop through each field somehow rather than checking each individually?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not certain, I think what you're trying to do is not directly possible in MySQL. I do know a workaround, though.

You can get a list of colums from `information_schema.columns`:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblExample' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

You could use this list of columns to automatically generate your triggers using a script. If you are using PHP, it would look a bit like this piece of (untested) example code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=information_schema;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?');

$stmt->bindValue(1, $myTableName);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $myDatabaseName);

$stmt->execute();

$triggerSql = '';

while (($columnName = $stmt->fetchColumn()) !== false) {
    $triggerSql .= 'IF (OLD.' . quoteIdentifier($columnName) . ' <> NEW.' . quoteIdentifier($columnName) . ') THEN
  INSERT INTO tblChanges(object_type, object_id, change_type, field_name, field_before, field_after, log_time) VALUES (\'example\', NEW.id, \'edited\', ' . $db->quote($columnName) . ', OLD.' . quoteIdentifier($columnName) . ', NEW.' . quoteIdentifier($columnName) . ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END IF;';

}

echo 'CREATE TRIGGER ' . quoteIdentifier($myTriggerName) . ' AFTER UPDATE ON ' . quoteIdentifier($myTableName) . '
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
' . $triggerSql . '
END;';
```

Note that it may (or may not) be better to log to a 'history table' *per table* instead of to one huge 'history table' for all tables. In that case, you could create a copy of each table and just add an extra ID and timestamp column for tracking. This approach has its own disadvantages but would be slightly more semantically correct. In this approach, you might consider simply adding the row to the history table as soon as the AFTER UPDATE trigger runs, skipping any tedious checks. Check for changes between rows when you're looping over them in the software (for visualization, for example) instead of in the database. As I said, it may or may not be better but it's worth considering.